# ? Operator in rust causing error on Result type

Tags: rust

New to Rust. I'm trying to convert a Result type using the `?` operator. Commented out code works however replacing it with the line which uses the operator produces this error:

```
^^ cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `()`
```

Why is this? I thought using the ? should always work when Dealing with Result types however most of the time I try it insists () is being returned even when a match statement demonstrates it returning a Result type. I've seen this type of syntax in documentation which says it should be fine.

```
pub fn new(csv_file: String, portfolio_key: String, volatility_divisor: f64, raw_threshold: f64) {
    let file = File::open(&csv_file[..]).expect("Bad file name");
    let mut reader = csv::Reader::from_reader(file);
    for l in reader.records() {
        //                let l = match l {
        //                    Ok(file) => file,
        //                    Err(error) => panic!("ERROR: {}", error),
        //                };
        let l = l?;
        println!("{:?}", l);
    }
}
```

Comment: **tl:dr :** enclosing function must return `Result` with same `Error` type.